# Grunts, moans, breathing, etc

Tags: mixing, dialogue, production-sound, stems, m-and-e

What do you guys do about character sounds such as grunts in a fight or breathing, etc. Do you put it in the DX stem or the PX? Is it considered native dialogue to the movie or can it go into production effects? Certain sounds are just really hard to re-create in foley and out of our budget. It's an indie film. Would really appreciate tips!

Answer (score 1):

DX. It's either going to be production DX or ADR, both of which will end up in the DX stem for the premix.

Usually though, its going to be a matter of taste for the dialogue editor, who can work with the re-recording mixer to figure out how they would like to see the tracks.